# Non-abelian group in which $\forall_{a,b\in G} (ab)^3=a^3b^3$

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Give an example of a non-abelian group, in which $(ab)^3=a^3b^3$ for every element $a,b$ in $G$.

I understand that such a group should be of order divisible by 3 (see [Problem from Herstein on group theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282597/problem-from-herstein-on-group-theory)). Also, it is easily seen that $(ab)^3=a^3b^3 \iff (ba)^2=a^2b^2$. But I can't come up with one single example.

Comment: Any nonabelian group of exponent 3, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try the group of triangular $3 \times 3$ matrices over the field with 3 elements, with 1's on the diagonal. This group has exponent 3, that is for every $g \in G$, it holds that $g^3=1$. Can you see that $|G|=27$?

Comment: I'd just like to add: as evidence that $G$ is not abelian, note that $A = \pmatrix{ 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\}$ and $B = \pmatrix{ 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 \\}$ satisfy $AB \neq BA$.

Comment: Yes good remark - on the other hand, I was hoping that the OP would figure that (non-abelianess) out for him/herself.

Comment: Ah, I suppose I could have been more delicate there.  I wanted to save OP the hunt for non-commuting matrices, which is particularly unpleasant if you don't know what to look for.