# If $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$ then $(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{n^2-n}=e$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I was trying to prove [that statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/282713/126389) from Resident Dementor's answer, namely:

> We can prove that if for an integer $n$ and every $a,b\in G$, $(ab)^n=a^nb^n$, then
>   $$(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{n(n-1)}=e$$
>   The proof is easy. In fact,
>   $$(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{n^2}=[(aba^{-1}b^{-1})^n]^n=[a^n(ba^{-1}b^{-1})^n]^n=...=a^nb^na^{-n}b^{-n}\\\
>  (aba^{-1}b^{-1})^{n}=(ab)^n(a^{-1}b^{-1})^n=a^nb^na^{-n}b^{-n}$$

I was able to understand only the first two equalities and i was trying to do different methods but no results. Can anyone demonstrate detailed proof, please?

Comment: I don't see how $[a^n(ba^{-1}b^{-1})^n]^n=\dots =a^nb^na^{-n}b^{-n}$ either.

Comment: @Shaun, It's strange, however 10 people upvote that question. Maybe it is true but I cannot derive the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$[a^n(ba^{-1}b^{-1})^n]^n$$
$$=[a^nba^{-n}b^{-1}]^n$$
$$=[a^nba^{-n}]^nb^{-n}$$
$$=a^nb^na^{-n}b^{-n}$$

Comment: That's much better! I mark your answer as the best answer.